# htm2pdf itextpdf external css not taking affect

Tags: java, html, css, itext, html2pdf

I am not sure why `<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/print.css"/>` is not working, My css is not affecting nor supporting my html code and java code I am using to convert as pdf is this method, there is no error in PDF. Is there something I am missing?

```
@Override
public DataHandler Version(StringBuffer htmlSrc, String documentTitle) throws Exception {
    DataHandler dataHandler = null;
    String outputFile = "testNow.pdf";
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = htmlSrc;
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toString().getBytes());
            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(bais);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile));) {

          ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
          HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(bais, os, properties);

        dataHandler = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(outputFile));
        return dataHandler;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error @ getPDFVersion():" + e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

```
.inetd1 { /* column row style use only with grid tables */
                background-color : White;
                /*border-style : solid;*/
                font-weight : bold;
                padding-bottom : 1px;
                padding-left : 1px;
                padding-right : 1px;
                padding-top : 1px;
                text-align : left;
                /*border-color : Black;
                border : thin;*/
                font-size : xx-small;
            }
```

```
<html>
   <head>
      <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/print.css"/>
      <style> .pagebreak { page-break-after: always; }</style>
   </head>
   <div align="center">
      <h4>ssssss</h4>
   </div>
   <table align="center" summary="Header d">
      <tbody>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Pr</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> Low  Clinics</td>
         </tr>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Grae:</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> Lf Alabama</td>
         </tr>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Rep:</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> 424C</td>
         </tr>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Fut Period:</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> L8</td>
         </tr>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Report Period:</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> 01/01/2018 to 06/30/2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr valign="top">
            <td align="right=" valign="top" class="inetd1">
               <div align="right">Repus:</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left=" class="inetd1"> Sad</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <br/>
   <div style="overflow-x:auto; width:90%; margin: 0 auto" id = "Group13950">
     <table  border = "1" width = "100%" align = "center" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "1" summary = "Form 13424-C | Low Income Taxpayer Clinic (LITC) - Advocacy Information header" class = "generaltable">
       <tr>
          <td valign="top"  colspan = "1" rowspan = "1" class = "header">
             <span id = Col183980><b>
             <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000" style="border-style: none" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" summary="Form n Date:  XX/XX/XXXX"  >
                <td>
                   <table style="width:100%">
                      <tr>
                         <td  align="left" style="position: float;">
                            <font style ="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
                            Form
                            </font>
                            <font style ="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;">
                            <B>134</B>
                            </font>
                         </td>
                         <td  align="center" style="position: float;">
                            <font style ="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9 pt;">
                            Depasury - IntS
                            </font>
                            <br>
                            <font style ="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;">
                            <B>Low
                            <br>Adrmation</B>
                         </td>
                         </td>
                         <td  align="right" style="position: float;">
                            <font style ="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
                            <B>OMB <br></B>15
                            </font>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                      </td>
                   </table>
                </tr>
              </table>
 </<html>
```

POM dependencies

```
  <dependency>
               <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
               <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
               <version>7.1.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
               <artifactId>io</artifactId>
               <version>7.1.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
               <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
               <version>7.1.2</version>
           </dependency>        
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
               <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
               <version>7.1.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
             <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
             <version>2.0.2</version>
           </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a proper URL in the link href?

Comment: Yes that is right one

Comment: `"C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/print.css"` is not a valid URL at all.  Perhaps you meant `"file:///C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/print.css"`?

Comment: I meant this one HREF="file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/print.css"

Comment: after file I see only one slash in my import will it be the cause?

Comment: @Juke hey, do you happen to have logging configured for your application? If you search for messages from `com.itextpdf.*`, you should be able to find something relevant if there was a problem in the CSS file resolution.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should try to open your HTML in browser and see if the CSS is picked up by the browser. Have you tried that?

Comment: @AlexeySubach in teh logs I can see few logs related to CssUtils but its not an erorr and in HTML its working good

Comment: @Juke allright, I think another important thing to try is to update your dependencies. There have been a few releases already after the ones you are using. Can you try with `iText Core` 7.1.7 and `pdfHTML` 2.1.4?

Comment: @AlexeySubach Exceptions are like these it says and Error but its not actually there in css file ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.util.CssUtils: parseAbsoluteLength: Unknown absolute metric length parsed " pt".

Comment: yes I will try those now

Comment: I have one my question I am not using any pdfdocument or  pdwriter is that the case where its not taking the css?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I have one more question in the logs there is Error related to "pt"  that can be the reason why its not interpreting the css file?

Comment: @Juke `HtmlConverter` uses `PdfDocument` and `PdfWriter` under the hood. For the `pt` error, it's because you have definitions in points in styles: `font-size: 10pt;`.

Comment: I think you should a) try the new version and b) try the link in the format @VGR proposed

Comment: @AlexeySubach I did update new version and also formated link but was not working. I have made the css file inputstream and attcahed in the head its now working good. since dependency is not allowing the direct import.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Do we need to write separate configurations to display page numbers in Table Of Content and end of the page?

Comment: @Juke you can use `@page` media and content CSS property to display counter(page)

Comment: @AlexeySubach I ahve used this  I have used this Its not working at.page {
    at.bottom-right { 
        padding-right:20px; 
        content: "Page " counter(page); 
    } 
} its not working , I used at. because stackoverflow is not allowing me to put that char

Comment: @Juke this is the exactly correct way of adding page number at the bottom of the page. Are you using the latest 7.1.7 version and pdfHTML 2.1.4? If so, you should make another question with an HTML+CSS example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @AlexeySubach yes I am using the exact versions. I am trying to include using java forloop but neither works.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Here is the another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963065/cannot-draw-elements-on-already-flushed-pages